# Can Omniknight's abilities affect himself?

Tags: dota-2

From Dota 2 wiki I read that Omniknight's Abilities, Purification affects an ally and enemies, while Heavenly Grace affects an ally. But Dota 2 wiki doesn't mention whether Purification and Heavenly Grace can be applied to Omniknight himself (!). This is confusing because from Dotacinema (youtube), both Abilities Purification and Heavenly Grace can be used to heal or give spell immunity to the Omniknight himself(!). So, can Purification, Heavenly Grace, and Guardian Angel all be applied to allies and the Omniknight himself as the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of Omniknight's abilities can be used on himself.  This was something I found unintuitive at first as well (with Dazzle's Shallow Grave, but same concept).

Most ally-targeted spells can be used on yourself because you are an ally of yourself :)

Comment: Why Dota2 wiki doesn't mention this AT ALL ?? this is weird

Comment: It should be written AFFECTS : self , allies.